# Backup Linux to DVD

Tags: linux, backup, dvd

I'm currently using [Cedar Backup](http://cedar-backup.sourceforge.net/) to backup my home directories, system config, etc to DVD+RW.  It does, however, have limitations; backups can't exceed a single disk, restores are totally manual, etc.

Most Linux backup software assumes you have a tape.  [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/) is an exception, but it's DVD support is broken and fixing it doesn't seem to be a priority.

What other software for backing up linux to DVD is there?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Mondo rescue](http://www.mondorescue.org/), which can backup an entire system to DVD and even make the first DVD bootable so you can restore from bare metal without needing to install any software.

If you want a more manual, command-line approach you could also use [dar](http://dar.linux.free.fr/), which is similar to 'tar' but can generate an archive divided into a number of fixed-size "slices" which can be burned to individual DVDs.

Answer (score 1):

I use [backupninja](https://labs.riseup.net/code/wiki/backupninja) to make DVD images using it's makecd handler, and then burn them manually.  There's a burncd handler available in Debian (also [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=317356)) in order to actually burn the DVD itself while the backup is running, which I tried for a while but then forgot to replace the DVD, which was no good for actual backups.